# Returning only a few properties of an object

Tags: c#

If I've got a list of objects with, let's say, 10 properties, and I want to return a list of these objects but with only 3 properties of the 10 available, how would I do that?

```
public class Example
{
    public int attr1 {get;set;}
    public int attr2 {get;set;}
    public int attr3 {get;set;}
    public int attr4 {get;set;}
    public int attr5 {get;set;}
}

return ExampleList; //have the return value be a list with only attr1, 2, and 3 visible.
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ with [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method and return [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
var result = ExampleList.Select(x => new { x.attr1, x.attr2, x.attr3 });
```

Or, explicitly define your own class with 3 properties, this case is usual if you convert from Domain Entity to View Model or Dto object:

```
class Dto
{
    public int Pro1 { get; set; }
    public int Pro2 { get; set; }
    public int Pro3 { get; set; }
}

var result = ExampleList.Select(x => new Dto { 
                                       Pro1 = x.attr1,
                                       Pro2 = x.attr2,
                                       Pro3 = x.attr3 
                                    });
```

Or if you just want a *dump* class, you can use [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
var result = ExampleList.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.attr1, x.attr2, x.attr3));
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but why, in the first example (the anonymous type example) do I get "Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage" error?

Answer (score 0):

Make the properties nullable and use [Object Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx).

```
public class Example
{
    public int? attr1 {get;set;}
    public int? attr2 {get;set;}
    public int? attr3 {get;set;}
    public int? attr4 {get;set;}
    public int? attr5 {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ projection operator:

```
var resultList = ExampleList.Select(x => new
    {
        x.attr1,
        x.attr2,
        x.attr3
    });
```

Or if you need to specify another prop names:

```
var resultList = ExampleList.Select(x => new
    {
        PropName1 = x.attr1,
        PropName2 = x.attr2,
        PropName2 = x.attr3, // <- The last comma can be leaved here.
    });
```

Pay attention that resulted enumerable is not of type `Example` but of pre-compile (not runtime) created anonymous type.